# Use LINQ to get comma separated list from different table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql, linq

I'm using ASP.NET and have a GridView that I want to populate with data from 2 tables.  Right now, I have the following query:

```
var carListData = from x in db.cars
                  orderby x.carName
                  select new { x.carId, x.carName, locationIDs = string.Empty };
carList.DataBind();
```

Now, I want to set locationIDs to be a comma-separated string.  I need to look up all the locations that sell each car.  I have a table called db.locationCars and it has a locationId column and a carId column.  Multiple locations can have the same carId.  How do I update my carDataList query to get all the locations that sell each car so those locationIDs can be displayed in the carList gridview?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Using a `GroupJoin` should work.  If the first gives you translation to SQL issues, try the second.

```
var carListData = db.cars
                    .GroupJoin(db.locationCars,
                              (o,i) => o.carId,
                              (o,i) => i.carId,
                              (o,i) => new { o.carId, o.carName, locationIds = string.Join(",", i.Select(l => l.locationId)))
                    .OrderBy(g => g.carName);
```

Version performing the string join in memory

```
var carListData = db.cars
                    .GroupJoin(db.locationCars,
                              (o,i) => o.carId,
                              (o,i) => i.carId,
                              (o,i) => new { o.carId, o.carName, locations = i.Select(l => l.locationId))
                    .OrderBy(g => g.carName)
                    .ToList()
                    .Select(g => new { g.carId, g.carName, locationIds = string.Join(",", g.locations));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( var car in carList )
        {
            var locationIds = Locations.Where( loc => loc.CarId == car.Id ).Select( loc => loc.Id );
            car.locationIDs = string.Join( ",", locationIds );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your foreign keys are defined properly in the database, and your entity framework model his updated with those foreign keys. Then you would have a collection of locationCars in each Car object with the locationIds you need.

Create a new object called carListData and select into that object. This object can convert your collection of LocationCars into a csv of locationIds.